# Android has Services, but is there an equivalent or way to implement similar functionality in iOS?

Tags: iphone, android, service, ios4

In my Android app I can easily create a Service object that can run in the background to perform arbitrary routines. In my case I have a Service which maintains a connection with a server and upon receiving messages it notifies the user. This service is only turned on when a particular activity enters its onPause or onStop cycle and is turned off when the activity is resumed

Is there some way to do this with iOS? I've poked around and only have come across this page on the Apple developer site:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Everything described there doesn't seem to satisfy my needs so I wanted to check with the SO community to see if anyone has some sort of solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apple way to do what you are talking about is to use the Push Notification Service.  Generally speaking in 4.x+ you have [Remote Notifications and Local Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/).  You don't have to go direct, [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/) offers a web service option if you don't like hacking raw TCP streams.

Also, if the push service is just not compatible with your architecture (a twitter client for example) when your app quits you can request more time for background execution to finish downloads / schedule more work with the APIs you found at that URL.

It's kind of cheating, but you can register your app for location updates using the UIBackgroundModes Info.plist property and when you get a location update, "just so happen to also check for new messages" at that time as well.  In effect this is piggie-backing your message polling code on the location change event.

Comment: I understand the push notifications and I've considered it, but I wouldn't trade the complexity for the functionality. Any idea if something needs to be actively executing during the background process? Say for instance I'm waiting for an update from an HTTP service thats guaranteed to come in within a few minutes?

Comment: You handle the events, and you'll get to execute anything you want.  It can be NSThread sleep for all the system cares AFAIK

Comment: there is a limitation on drawing.  especially opengl, you'll get killed if you try to call any of those calls

Answer (score 0):

As far as running a custom service in the background, you can't, at least not for longer than 10 minutes, once your background process exceeds 10 minutes your app will be killed.

If you want to do consistent backgrounding in iOS you have to use one of the provided Multitasking APIs that are detailed in the link you provided

Comment: The provided APIs don't seem to indicate that I'll get what I want. Is 10 minutes the maximum amount of time you get when requesting background time to complete a task? If so, where is this 10 minutes documented?

Comment: Evidently it is not in the API Reference which seems strange, but it was in the release notes for 4.0. `The time limit for task completion changed from 5 minutes to 10 minutes.` http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iPhoneSDK-4_0/  Check out the Multitasking section.